# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 Export Metadata in RPD and Catalog

Tags: oracle, metadata, extract, business-intelligence, obiee

Metadata export within the RPD (utilitys -> RPD documentation) of the latest OBI release works fine:

The displayed data ranges from *Subject Area* to different stages of the RPD to the *physical table* and *physical column*.

I am facing problems exporting metadata (*Create Catalog Report*, see pic.) using the catalogmanager: ideally I want to extract the information of elements within dashboards connected to the subject area/tables. In this case: establishing a link between metadata (rpd) and metadata (catalog).

I have tried to use *Dashboard* as type to report on (choosing analysis in the dropdown and generating output works fine - *Dashboard* generates *inconsistent* output): 
[image: see 1]

The advanced options somehow have no impact on the generated file:
[image]

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated. (I did not try this option yet: I can use the catmanager in the command line along with wlst scripting - generating the prospective of automation of this process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Dashboards do not reference RPD presentation layer objects. Only analyses, prompts, filters or the likes do
b) As soon as your presentation layer has aliases for any object it won't work anymore anyways